# Teach a novice how to import a photo and upload it to eBay

Tags: gnome, firefox, browser, photo

Is there an easier way to upload files in Web browser (HTML) file upload forms other than noting/cutting a file location and typing/pasting that location into a Browse... dialog? I've heard [drag and drop upload is on the way](http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/drag-and-drop-upload), but looks like eBay isn't using it yet.

My Dad was frustrated trying to import a photo off his digital camera and upload it to eBay. He had the import part figured out (GNOME/F-Spot does a pretty good job with that), but was stuck because he didn't know how to browse to the photo.

In my older F-Spot (on Ubuntu 10.04), when you right click on a photo there's a "Copy Photo Location" option. This copies the full path of the file into the clipboard, and I can easily use this for browser file upload forms. Apparently this was changed in his newer F-Spot (on Ubuntu 10.10)... now it's just "Copy Photo". I don't know what "Copy Photo" does, but it doesn't put the full photo file path in the clipboard.

I came up with a many-step process so he could do this on his own. Anyone know a better way? This is just crazy:

> 1. Import photo to F-Spot.
> 2. Double-click on photo.
> 3. Copy/remember photo filename (something like DSCN0471.JPG).
> 4. Click "Places" in the panel on the top of the desktop.
> 5. Choose "Search for Files...".
> 6. Paste or type in the filename next to "Name contains:".
> 7. Click "Find".
> 8. If the file is found, note the Folder listed (if not, try searching again). You may leave the "Search for Files" window open.
> 9. When visiting the site where you will upload the photo, you'll be prompted to upload a file. The file upload "form" will include buttons such as "Browse..." and "Upload".
> 10. First click "Browse...".
> 11. Browse to the photo in the Folder listed in step 8. Click "Open" to choose that file. The window will close and you will return to the file upload form.
> 12. Click Upload.
> 13. Done!

Comment: Hi Adam. I've (amazingly) never used Ebay before, when uploading a photo, it DOES give you the ability to browse to, and select the photo, correct?

Comment: Yes. My 13-step guide was tested (only) with eBay.

Answer (score 2):

Well, perhaps a slightly less annoying way is right-clicking the photo in f-spot, going to Open With and selecting e.g. firefox. Then you can copy+paste the path to the file.

If the photos get imported to a particular folder, you could also add that folder as a "bookmark" on the left of the file chooser dialog.

Still, let's hope a newer version of f-spot comes with a less annoying method :)